# How to Localize UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile

Tags: localization, ios11, xcode9

I have an image with the word 'NEW' that should be localized to 'Nuevo', 'Nuovo', etc... based on locale. I am trying to find a way to localize this 'New' image in `UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile` in the `info.plist` file.

So what I have done is that I added a line in each `infoPlist.strings` for English:

```
"NEW" = "New";
```

And Spanish:

```
"NEW" = "Nuevo";
```

And Italian:

```
"NEW" = "Nuovo";
```

where `New`, `Nuevo` and `Nuovo` are the names of the image files in `images.xcassets`. And in `info.plist` I have set the key `UIApplicationShortcutItemIconFile` to "NEW"

But that doesn't work and I don't get an icon at all before the quick action title. Instead a big black dot.

It's also important to mention that localizing `UIApplicationShortcutItemTitle` works without a problem using same above technique!

Is there any other way to try localizing this icon?